# Specific selection of rows from a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting

Consider the following the matrix:

```
1 2 1 1
1 3 1 1
2 5 2 3
2 6 2 4 
2 6 2 4 
2 9 0 0 
3 4 5 6
3 4 1 1 
3 2 0 0
3 1 1 1 
.
.
.
```

I want to select the row(s) with the maximum value in column 2 for every unique value in column 1.

For eg. 
Answer should be:

```
1 3 1 1
2 9 0 0
3 4 5 6
3 4 1 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened to `3 4 5 6` Isn't it bigger than `3 2 1 1`?

Comment: What happens in the event of a tie?

Comment: @Sergio Sorry about that. Edited!

@ Dan print both if its a tie

Comment: To be honest I would have expected that this question specifies what part of the exercise you are struggling with. I mean your question readily translates to metacode: `1) split into groups by first column, 2) select inside groups based on 2nd col, 3) combine`

Comment: @bdecaf: right which is why I showed the obvious loop-based solution. Normally whenever I'm performing this sort of "data aggregation", `accumarray` comes to mind as showed in Dan's solution (slightly less readable, but definitely faster)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
%// Get a unique list of column 1 without changing the order in which they appear
[C1, ~, subs] = unique(M(:,1), 'stable');

%// Get the max value from column 2 corresponding to each unique value of column 1
C2 = accumarray(subs, M(:,2), [], @max);

%// Find the desired row indices
I = ismember(M(:,1:2), [C1, C2], 'rows');

%//Extract the rows
M(I, :)
```

Comment: you might run into troubles if `M(:,1)` is not valid indices... The fix is easy though: `[C1,~,M1] = unique(M(:,1), 'stable');` and `C2 = accumarray(M1, M(:,2), [], @max);`

Answer (score 1):

Some code to get you started:

```
% unique values in first column
col1 = unique(x(:,1));

% we first store results in a cell array (later converted to matrix)
xx = cell(numel(col1), 1);

for i=1:numel(col1)
    % rows with the same value in column 1
    rows = x(x(:,1) == col1(i),:);

    % maximum value along column 2
    mx = max(rows(:,2));

    % store all rows with the max value (in case of ties)
    xx{i} = rows(rows(:,2)==mx,:);
end

% combine all resulting rows
xx = vertcat(xx{:});
```

The result for the matrix you've shown:

```
>> xx
xx =
     1     3     1     1
     2     9     0     0
     3     4     5     6
     3     4     1     1
```